# tryCatch crashes while nls fit

Tags: conditional-statements, try-catch, nls

I am trying to fit a non-linear model using `nls` function. The model has a conditioning and works by groups therefore I try to implement a loop which covers over 300 combinations of starting values. I am using `tryCatch` but to my surprise the loop crashes, I guess because of the starting values or lower and upper bounds.

```
tryCatch(
 
  for(r in 1:nrow(st4)){

    halfLE3[[r]] <- nls(

      inty ~ I(time < (position/velocity) + dinitial) * Inty_S0 +
        (time >= (position/velocity) + dinitial) *
        I(Intyf[probe] + (Inty_S0[probe] - Intyf) * 
            (exp(-Decay * (time - (position/velocity) + dinitial)))),
      
      data = Data4,

      algorithm = "port",

      control = list(warnOnly = TRUE),
      
      start = list(Decay=st4[r,3], dinitial=st4[r,2],
                   Intyf=rep(st4[r,4], length(levels(Data4$probe))), 
                   Inty_S0=rep(st4[r,5], length(levels(Data4$probe))),
                   velocity=st4[r,1]),
      
      lower = list(Decay= .1, dinitial=0.1, velocity=10, Intyf=0.1, inty_S0=.5),
      upper = list(Decay= 1, dinitial=10, velocity=8000, Intyf=1, inty_S0=1.5)
    )

  }

  ,error = function(e) {e}

)
```

st4 is a dataframe with 300 combinations of starting values.
probe refers to group.

Do you have any idea why the loop crashes even using the `tryCatch`? Do you have any idea what I can improve? I used the `nls.control` changing the maxiter and other parameters but works same as the control I use here above.

I would be very grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. The tryCatch should be located inside the for loop adding a bracket.

```
for(r in 1:nrow(st4)){

tryCatch({
nls()......

},error = function(e) {e}
)
}
```